# python - iterate list of column names and access to column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame called `df` want to iterate the `columns_to_encode` list and get the value of `df.column` but I'm getting the following error (as expected). Any idea about how cancould I do it?

```
columns_to_encode = ['column1','column2','column3']

for column in columns_to_encode:
    df.column 

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column'
```

Comment: slight chagne to your code - do `df[column]` `.dot` notation is discouraged for selecting columns

Comment: ohh true!! How can I miss that! thanks! @Umar.H

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, this will solve your issue:

```
columns_to_encode = ['column1','column2','column3']

for column in columns_to_encode:
    df[column]
```